# starting Websphere portal

Tags: windows, websphere, windows-xp, websphere-portal

I have installed WebSphere portal in my local machine , it was running fine till now.Today i installed IBM HTTP server and suddenly my web sphere portal is not starting .

I have a WAS profile, web sphere portal server and ibm http server in my local  machine which is running windows xp. All these are configured to run as windows service , now when i attempt to start the portal server i get below message:

```
 WASService running at the same time for 'IBMWAS70Service -WebSphere_Portal_V$AIN' Service not started
```

Any input on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you see the command which the Portal Server start is trying to use? Do you get anything in the WebSphere Portal server logs when you try to start the server?

Comment: Are you running Portal v7? It looks like you have WAS 7. Portal 7 has two processes, Server1 and the Portal process. Server 1 is for maintenance work. Make sure it is stopped before starting Portal.

Comment: I am using Portal 6.1 on WAS7. The command i am running is                  **IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\startServer.bat WebSphere_Portal**

Comment: Is it possible that you've changed default Portal ports to 80 and 443, which is colliding with IHS? Otherwise IHS should not interfere with your WebSphere Portal.

Comment: I have changed port to 81

Comment: What do you get in your WebSphere portal server logs when you try to start the server?

Comment: **
 WindowsServic 3   Timed out waiting for service to respond to command, after 1200 seconds.Failed to start service, or timed out while waiting for start to complete. Check the logs for details.
 AdminTool     A   ADMU7704E: Failed while trying to start the Windows Service associated with server: WebSphere_Portal; 
probable error executing WASService.exe: Starting Service: WebSphere_Portal_V$AIN
Timed out waiting for service to respond to command, after 1200 seconds.Failed to start service, or timed out while waiting for start to complete. Check the logs for details..**

Comment: And have you checked the SystemOut.log log and see what it says?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my machine and things worked fine :). Mostly likely there was some services created in windows services with same name or something of that sought which was rectified once i restarted my machine.